# E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "ž": syntax error when filtering recycler using Room

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, android-livedata

I am getting error with sql syntax written. I try to simply filter name of some field in entity using Room by replacing special chars with "regular" ones. Here is raw query:

```
    SimpleSQLiteQuery simple = new SimpleSQLiteQuery("SELECT * FROM station WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LOWER(" + stationName + "), \"ž\", \"z\"), \"Ž\", \"z\"), \"č\", \"c\"), \"Č\", \"c\"), \"š\", \"s\"), \"Š\", \"s\"), \"ć\", \"c\"), \"Ć\", \"c\") LIKE " + "\" REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LOWER(stationName), \"ž\", \"z\"), \"Ž\", \"z\"), \"č\", \"c\"), \"Č\", \"c\"), \"š\", \"s\"), \"Š\", \"s\"), \"ć\", \"c\"), \"Ć\", \"c\")"+ "\" ORDER BY stationName ASC");
```

I got error: E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "ž": syntax error and it does not matter what char i write in editText. I am missing something here. Thanks for help!

Comment: I see problems with your string concatenation.  Try building up the expression, starting with just one replacement. Only do cut and paste when you know it is working.

Comment: Try using single quotes for those strings...might work.. 
Ex: "'ž'"

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:

```
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM station WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LOWER(stationName), 'ž', 'z'), 'Ž', 'z'), 'č', 'c'), 'Č', 'c'), 'š', 's'), 'Š', 's'), 'ć', 'c'), 'Ć', 'c') LIKE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LOWER('" + station + "'), 'ž', 'z'), 'Ž', 'z'), 'č', 'c'), 'Č', 'c'), 'š', 's'), 'Š', 's'), 'ć', 'c'), 'Ć', 'c') ORDER BY stationName ASC";
```

Amit Jangid was correct. I replaced all with single quotes! Thank you